# Operators = vs. == in PHP

Tags: php, operators

I am learning basic PHP from a book, and from what I read, `=` is an assignment operator, and `==` is a comparison operator. So...

```
$x = 5;
$x == 5: true
```

...makes sense. However, the book gives an example which confuses me:

```
if (++$x == 10)
    echo $x;
```

Why ==? Aren't we trying to say "if ++$x equals 10, then echo $x"...? Then that would seem like: if (++$x = 10). The former would be like asking a question inside a conditional statement, which would be illogical or redundant.

Comment: The if-statement is basically reading "If we increment `$x` (permanently) and the new value equals 10, then echo `$x`" Less readable, but valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`==` means equality, so the conditional reads as:

If pre-incremented `$x` equals 10, echo `$x`

Single `=` is assignment, where a variable is set to contain a value:

```
$word = 'hello';
$number = 5;
// etc.

echo "I said $word $number times!";
```

Regarding the increment opperators:

You'll see things like `++$x` and `$i--` as you learn PHP (and/or other languages). These are increment/decrement operators. *Where* they're positioned in relation to the variable they're operating on is important.

If they're placed *before* the variable, like `++$x`, it's a pre-increment/decrement. This means the operation is performed before anything else can be done to the variable. If it's placed *after*, like `$x++`, it's a post-increment/decrement, and it means that the operation is performed afterward.

It's easiest to see in an example script:

```
$x = 5;

echo ++$x; // 6
echo $x++; // ALSO 6
echo $x; // NOW 7
```

Comment: Probably want to explain what a `pre-incremented` value is. Or else this is just as confusing to someone with little/no knowledge

Answer (score 0):

`++$x` is executed before the condition itself is evalutated, so this condition would be true:

```
$x = 9;
if (++$x == 10) {
    //this is executed
}
```

This can be used to build very short `while` loops:

```
// Count from 1 to 10
$i = 0
while ($i <= 10) {
    echo ++$i;
}
```

The difference between `$i++` and `++$i` is the order of incrementing and evaluation:

```
// Count from 0 to 9
$i = 0
while ($i <= 10) {
    echo $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend NOT incrementing/decrementing a variable within an if statement... it's not good for code readability.  In any case, you're still doing a comparison here, you're just ALSO incrementing the value of X.

Consider it this way:

```
if((++$x) == 10)
```

You have an expression on the left of the '==', which you are comparing to an expression on the right side.  The ++$x is evaluated first, then the result of that is compared to 10.

Comment: Great `for` loops though. Get it. Haha.

Answer (score 0):

What the book says is: If a variable is true at 10 then write the variable out. The `if` statement evaluates whether the condition is true or false.. so

```
   if ($x == 10)
```

is equally true when checked as:

```
   $x = 9
   if (++$x == 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

We always ask questions in conditional statements, and act on whether the result is true or false. If you said ++$x=10, you'd be saying "Add one to X, and then SET the value of X to be 10." Instead you want to know IF after we add one to X IS it equal to 10.

= means SET the expression on the left to be the value on the right
== means TELL ME TRUE if the expression on the left is the same as the value on the right

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `=` is assignment:

```
$Var = "String"; // $Var is now set to contain "string"
```

Whereas

`==` is a comparison operator:

```
if ($Var == "Value){
  // Since var is set to "string", the comparison fails

}
```

Your example:

```
if (++$x == 10){

}
```

Is the same as doing this:

```
 $i = 0;
 while ($i < $x){
  if ($x == 10){
   break;
  }
   ++$x;
 }
```